# Efficient update of the table field on each request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I want to update the user table field on each request if the user is authorized. I have not encountered such a task before. I tried to write on the `AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```
public function boot()
{
    if(Auth::id()) {
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $user->updated_at = Carbon::now()->setTimezone("America/Los_Angeles");
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

But in this case I could not take **access** to the authorized user.

Can I get access to the service provider to an authorized user?

Or solve this problem with creating **middleware**?

**Note:** I am doing this task to find out the time of the user's last activity.

Is the solution found right? Is there a load on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> by creating a new middleware try this one

```
php artisan make:middleware UserActivityUpdateMiddleware
```

> UserActivityUpdateMiddleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class UserActivityUpdateMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::User()) {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $user->updated_at = Carbon::now()->setTimezone("America/Los_Angeles");
            $user->save();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```